# .net core 2.0 tcp connection leak on azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

We have an Web API app service deployed to Azure that has a reasonable amount of traffic. We are using built in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, as well as web sockets with Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.

This means that we don't really control the TCP connections, it all just happens magically, both for inbound HTTP connections and DB connections.

Yet on Azure we are having an issue where our allocated connections just keep growing. It's like most of the time connections are reused and all is good (except i'd expect connections to drop a lot when no traffic, but it never does), but it seems like the number of connections that cannot be reused grows, so new connections are added until we hit the limit and the server dies.

In below image you can see how over 5 minutes before server went down, the connection count went up almost exactly by the number of requests being made.

[image]

I can't even figure out how to debug the server to see where connections are being made, since it's all done behind the scenes. Anybody have any suggestions on how to tackle this beast?

Thanks!

EDIT: Two more screenshots. One app that has same stupid behavior of creating large amounts of connections and hanging on to them, and another that seems to behave as it should. These are two apps we built with all the same frameworks, configurations and coding conventions, so really have no idea why they behave so differently...

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd start by looking at the code for non-disposed `DbContext`s, `HttpClient`s and the like.

Comment: That's the thing though, using EntityFramework, the code uses a single db context injected into controllers, so i'm not supposed to close it. And we don't use HttpClients directly, all networking is handled behind the scenes by asp.net MVC. Essentially I'm not creating/closing/disposing any connections, it's supposed to be handled by the frameworks.

Comment: That makes sense, but we couldn't have guessed whether you use DI properly or not (you didn't post any code). Have you turned on system logging? Maybe that tells you something

Comment: I did turn on every bit of logging i could find in Azure, haven't had a chance to dig through it yet. And i'm not even sure what i would be looking for. Any suggestions?

Comment: I didn't mean Azure logging, I meant the ASP.NET Core's one (which you do by adding loggers to the `LoggerFactory` in the `Startup` class